# Convert Node JS web application to mobile application using PhoneGap

Tags: node.js, cordova, express, mobile, phonegap

I have developed web application using HTML/CSS and Node JS. The next task is to convert this application to a mobile application using Phonegap. Even though my application is working perfectly fine on web, the node server is not working in the mobile application after the conversion. I suppose this is because of two reasons:

1. server.js and app.js files are in the root folder and not under the www>js folder. Because of this the phonegap is not able to convert these files and use it in mobile app.
2. I need to start the web application from command prompt using "npm start" command. I cannot run the mobile application in a similar manner.

I have no experience in NodeJS or mobile app development. Kindly provide some solution or links which i can follow to complete the task.

**UPDATE**

Solution provided by @Nisar might work in my case. But i need to access the methods written in other js files, not the methods of app.js. Kindly suggest a way to achieve the same.

Comment: Have you created the API using Node JS  and calling those service using Ajax?

Comment: No I am not using Ajax @Nisar

Answer (score 1):

You not able to convert it directly as app.

First you have to separate UI (front end) and services (back end). In front end you have to request through AJAX Api and server will respond as JSON.

To create the service in Node JS, use below example for GET and POST:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));


http.listen(1337, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:1337');
});

app.get('/call', function(req, res){
   var end = "{\"result\": \"success\"}";
   res.end(end); 
});

app.post('/getUserData', function(req, res){
    response = {
      first_name:req.body.first_name,
      last_name:req.body.last_name
   };
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

And use the same in your application using ajax with below URL:

Get: http://localhost:1337/call
Post: http://localhost:1337/getUserData

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I understood what you have suggested. But I need to access the methods from other js files not the methods of the app.js. How to call the methods of, for example, abc.js file?